# Org Export Throwing an Error

Tags: org-export

Forgive the (relative) newbie question here.  My org export to LaTeX just started throwing this error after I upgraded to Emacs 29.0

Here is output from *Org PDF LaTeX Output* buffer:

Latexmk: -pdflatex bad option

Latexmk: Bad options specified
Use
latexmk -help
to get usage information

Comment: You have a misconfigured `org-latex-pdf-process` variable. The default is `("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%o %f")` - note that the option is `-pdf`, *NOT* `-pdflatex`.

Comment: NickD: thanks very much.  I searched the variable and fixed it.  Much appreciated.